# Email-To-Case Issue (New Case Email Alert)

Tags: email2case, servicecloud, email-alert

I have set up a routing address support@mycompany.com

I have also setup a flow which is sending an email alert to send New case notifications to the clients. This email alert is using the same FromAddress (support@mycompany.com)

For some reason email alerts are not going on new cases. If I change the FromAddress on the email alert, the new case email goes out successfully.

Is that the expected behavior? Do I need 2 separate addresses? (one for routing and another for email alerts) ?